# How to convert Julian date to calendar date on Hive?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, julian-date

Is there any `Hive` function available to convert from `Julian` date to `calendar` date?

There are multiple types of `Julian` date. The `Julian` date I have takes `15001` for `2015-01-01`.

I couldn't find any relevant information on this page:

[Hive Manual -  Date Functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

Answer (score 0):

```
 date_add('2015-01-01', juliadate - 15001)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add.

The below is for julian date format `yyyyDDD`

Input_julian_date : `2006121`

```
substr(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(cast(Input_julian_date as int) as string),'yyyyDDD')),1,10)
```

Output : `2006-05-01`

Answer (score 0):

Using "yyyyDDD" correctly converts Julian dates in Hive.

For example, I had a string column like "201707299999ABC" where the first 7 digits were the Julian date:

```
TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(SUBSTRING(my_julian_column, 0, 7), "yyyyDDD")))
```

Produces 2017-03-13 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Julian Date Format -- yyyyDDD
The Date Format which is expected -- 'yyyy-MM-dd'

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(cast(**julianl_date_col** as string),'yyyyDDD'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```